# resxResourceReader only read when xml:space is present

Tags: c#, xml, resx

I am surely missing something small here. I am trying to open multiple resx files, load them into a dictionary, then cross reference a translation file. The problem is that when I open up the resx file with resxResourceReader, it reads in all the the form setup data as well. I.E. container information, control names, etc.

Now I noticed in the resx file that the entries I want have "xml:space" along with them. What is the correct way to only get the strings I want, and leave all the other stuff behind?

Thanks!

```
            foreach (String s in sourceLocations)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> sourceTemp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dictionary<string, object> Temp = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            using (ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(s))
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in rsxr)
                {
                    string[] parts = s.Split('\\');
                    if (!entry.Key.ToString().Contains(">>"))
                    {
                        sourceTemp.Add(parts[parts.Count() - 1] + "_" + entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
                sources.Add(sourceTemp);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this later, this ended up working :

```
        foreach (String s in sourceLocations)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> sourceTemp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dictionary<string, object> Temp = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            using (ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(s))
            {
                rsxr.UseResXDataNodes = true;
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in rsxr)
                {
                    string[] parts = s.Split('\\');
                    if ((!entry.Key.ToString().Contains(">>")))
                    {
                        if (isNodeString((ResXDataNode)entry.Value))
                        sourceTemp.Add(parts[parts.Count() - 1] + "_" + entry.Key.ToString(), getNodeValue((ResXDataNode)entry.Value));
                    }
                }
                sources.Add(sourceTemp);
            }
        }


    private string getNodeValue(ResXDataNode node)
    {
        if (node.FileRef == null)
        {
            return node.GetValue((ITypeResolutionService)null).ToString();
        }
        else return String.Empty;
    }

    private bool isNodeString(ResXDataNode node)
    {
        string result =  node.GetValueTypeName((ITypeResolutionService)null);
        if (result.Contains("System.String")) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```